# Regex for a word that repeats only the chars i provide?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Ok so what im trying to do is match words like "lol" and "lollll" and "llllol" and "llllooooollll" and "loool" but not "pfftlol" or "lolpfft" etc.

my current code is

```
_.each(req.room._settings.automod.cussing.words, function(word)
{
    if(req.message.text.match(new RegExp('\\b'+word.split('').join('+?')+'\\b', 'gi')))
    {
        if(req.user && req.user.cache.automod.cussing === 0)
        {
            req.user.cache.automod.cussing = 1;
            req.write(req.user.name+", Please refrain from cussing in your messages this is your first and only warning next time you will be deleted.");
            req.room.delLastUser(req.user.name, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            req.room.delLastUser(req.user.name, 1);
        }
    }
});
```

and out of it

```
req.message.text.match(new RegExp('\\b'+word.split('').join('+?')+'\\b', 'gi'))
```

also lets say that req.room._settings.automod.cussing.words is ['lol','what'] since i dont want to list actual cuss words

and req.message.text is 'hah lollll hey'

also this is going through an _.each statement or foreach 
I'm using NodeJS

right now it returns the word as long as it partially matches

anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I have no clue what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: well im trying to match only one word that may or may not have characters repeated out of an entire string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from Ismael Miguel is correct

```
/\b(l)+(o)+(l)+\b/
```

which looks like this in my code

`var reg = '\\b('+cuss.split('').join(')+(')+')+\\b';
req.message.text.match(new RegExp(reg, 'gi'));`

Comment: You should put the answer in a separated line. It's incredibly hard to read when you use backticks.  And good catch with the `i` modifier: I wouldn't remember that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
/.*\b(l+o+l+)\b.*/
```

```js
var strings = ["who is lol", "looolll am i", "rofl llllooll", "pfftlol", "lolwho", "anotherlol", "lllllol hehe"];

for(var i = 0; i < strings.length; ++i){
var match = strings[i].match(/.*\b(l+o+l+)\b.*/);
  if (match)
    document.write( match[0] + "<br>") ;
}
```

Comment: no its out of a string like 'hey looollll hah' it should be able to match lol out of that but not 'hey lollllpfft hah' or 'hey pfftlolll hah'

Comment: also ^ matches l only if l is at the begginging of the string and $ matches l only if l is at the end of the string thats not what i want after all the string will contain multiple words

Comment: Try this: `/\b(l)+(o)+(l)+\b/`

Comment: @IsmaelMigeul /\b(l)+(o)+(l)+\b/ works and is what im looking for thankyou

Comment: @KamijouTouma Just one thing: `/\b(l)+(o)+(l)+\b/g` <- the `g` modifier is important. And you can do like this: `'('+('lol'.split('').join(')+(')+')+' to form the regex and you can use `Array.join` in each match to get the whole word.

Comment: @caeth that code is wrong and is also for a html i said i was using nodejs and nodejs is tagged so why are you doing javascript for html?